# How to re-initiate a setInterval

Tags: javascript

I use setInterval like so:

```
game.clock.interval = window.setInterval( game.clock_update, game.clock.delay );
```

I then later call a function to clear the interval:

```
game.clock_stop = function() {
    clearInterval(game.clock.interval);
}
```

Edit:

The real issue seems to be when I try to call the method that starts the interval agian. When a certain element (in my case an 'i' tag) is clicked I have it use the clearInterval function above; At the same exact time, I open a Colorbox..., I'm trying to resume the interval when I call onClosed for colorbox.

```
$("#pause").on("click",function(){
    game.pause();
    game.clock_stop();
});

game.pause = function() {
    $.colorbox({href:"pause.php", title:"The Game Is Paused"});
         onClosed:function(){
              game.clock_start();
    }
};
```

Comment: Call `setInterval()` again, like you did the first time.

Comment: Title isn't entirely accurate anymore, but I've edited the post, if anyone knows how to use colorbox, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: based on new info you added to your question.

The code for your `game.pause()` method looks wrong.  the `onClosed:` definition doesn't appear to be part of any object so it's probably not being attached to your colorbox at all.

I'm guessing that it should be this:

```
game.pause = function() {
    $.colorbox({
         href:"pause.php", 
         title:"The Game Is Paused",
         onClosed:function(){
              game.clock_start();
         }
    });
};
```

---

You just have to call `setInterval()` again just like you did the first time:

```
game.clock.interval = window.setInterval( game.clock_update, game.clock.delay );
```

This will start a new interval timer based on exactly when you make the new call to `setInterval()`.

---

If you're going to do this in several places, then just like you have a `clock_top()` method, you may want to make a `clock_start()` method:

```
game.clock_start = function() {
    // if clock not already running, start it
    if (!game.clock.interval) {
        game.clock.interval = setInterval(game.clock_update, game.clock.delay);
    }
}

game.clock_stop = function() {
    clearInterval(game.clock.interval);
    // clear saved timer so we know the clock is not running any more
    game.clock.interval = null;
}
```

So, anytime you want to start it, you can just call `game.clock_start()`.

Comment: hmm, this is exactly what I had originally tried... it must be something else I'm doing. I'll edit my post.

Comment: @Corjava - see what I've added to the beginning of my answer.

Comment: haha, yeah, I'm learning as I go, I should have realized this.
Thanks